# Eclipse issue with linuxmint

Tags: eclipse, linux-mint

I'm facing the same issue described in the picture : http://dentrassi.de/wp-content/uploads/eclipse1.png?cd7ade .
Basically the size of the toolbars and size of the eclipse is huge and ugly! I have searched the internet for a solution but I didn't find a fix.
Does anyone know how can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 links to fix the eclipse issue:
http://blog.nanthrax.net/2012/07/change-tab-font-in-eclipse-juno/
https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1168281

But still the toolbar icons are large. At least it looks better. If I find the full fix i'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to identify a good solution for this problem look at the next screenshot ...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5XuLGzBQTGBNy10bVdxNExkclk/edit?usp=sharing

[Linux Mint 14 Nadia]

Open a shell or exploring window and navigate to:
/usr/share/themes/Mint-X/gtk-2.0/gtkrc

Then make a backup and replace with the file in this link here 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5XuLGzBQTGBOEVIZ19BcWhVM28/edit?usp=sharing

... it all was matter of playing with the CSS properties and make the padding values and widths smaller.

(Note: I also made some small adjusts on the CSS IDE level as follows:)

Windows > Preferences > General > Appearance

I replaced this CSS Entry  on all themes:

```
/*
.MPartStack {
    swt-tab-renderer: null;
    swt-selected-tabs-background: #FFFFFF #ECE9D8 100%;
    swt-simple: false;
    swt-mru-visible: true;
}
*/

.MPartStack {
    font-size: 9;
    font-family: "Droid Sans";
    swt-simple: false;
    swt-mru-visible: false;
}
```

And then selected a smaller font:

Windows > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts

Open to display Java item and select Java Editor Text font

Click Edit and select a smaller and better font.

Have fun, hope it helps!